# java: can't rethrow exception: Unhandled exception type Exception

Tags: java, exception

I'd like to catch an exception, log it, set a flag, and the rethrow the same exception

I have this code:

```
public Boolean doJobWithResult() {
    boolean result = true;
    final Feed feed = Feed.findById(feedId);
    try {
        feed.fetchContents();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        result = false;
        Logger.info("fetching feed(%d) failed", feedId);
        throw ex;
    }
    return result;
}
```

But eclipse complains at throw ex, telling that "Unhandled exception type Exception", and suggests me to add a try-catch block around it.

In fact, I want the process calling this method to handle the exception, and not handle it myself... I just want to return true if everything goes ok, and log it if there's an exception

On the other hand, I can wrap the exception inside another exception, but I can't throw the same one..

any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think there are various things to mention here:

1. You either want `doJobWithResult()` to return true on success and false on failure, or return nothing on success and throw an exception on failure.
   Both at the same time is not possible. In the first case, catch the Exception, log it and return false, in the second case change your signature to return `void` and throw *an* exception and handle it in the caller.
2. It's a *Don't* to catch an exception, log it and rethrow it. Why? Because a potential caller of your method does not know that you are already logging it, and migh log it as well.
   Either throw an exception (in which case the caller has to deal with it) or catch it and handle it (log it).
3. Note that throwing `Exception` does not give the caller of your method any clue about what might potentially go wrong in your method, it's always better to throw more specific exceptions, or to wrap an exception in a user-defined one and rethrow it.
4. Moreover, if you throw `Exception`, a caller might be tempted to catch `Exception` without noticing that this will also catch every RuntimeException (since its derived from `Exception`), which might not be desired behavior.

Comment: all answers were pretty useful, I think this one also gives a few hints about how to deal with exceptions...

Comment: Most of this is spot on, but the only counter point I want to raise is with #2. It highly depends on your application structure, but in the case of building a REST API, a multi-tiered approach of layering exception handling can work well. For example, you can handle the exception when it is thrown with logging then throw a new wrapper exception as suggested in #3. Something like `RecoverableClientException` and `UnrecoverableClientException` can let calling code know how it can proceed. Wrappers can also help decide what kind of response and HTTP status code to send back to the client.

Answer (score 8):

Your doJobWithResult method needs to declare that it can throw Exception:

```
public Boolean doJobWithResult() {
```

becomes

```
public Boolean doJobWithResult() throws Exception {
```

Answer (score 6):

You can throw the same exception if you add `throws Exception` to your method signature.
Otherwise you can throw a [RuntimeException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html).

```
public Boolean doJobWithResult() { 
    boolean result = true; 
    final Feed feed = Feed.findById(feedId); 
    try { 
        feed.fetchContents(); 
    } catch (Exception ex) { 
        result = false; 
        Logger.info("fetching feed(%d) failed", feedId); 
        throw new RuntimeException(ex); 
    } 
    return result; 
}
```

In such a case, you won't need to indicate that `public Boolean doJobWithResult()` throws something but make sure you handle it properly later on (catch or expect your thread to stop... it's a RuntimeException afterall).

Answer (score 3):

Since `Exception` is [checked](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129), an alternative to catching the `Exception` is to declare your method as throwing it:

```
public Boolean doJobWithResult() throws Exception {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Simple and straight forward answer. A 10 point bonus from me :)

Answer (score 3):

If doJobWithResult doesn't have to handle the exception, then remove the catch block and add "throws Exception" to the method signature. The exception logging can be done in the class/method that have to deal with the Exception in a corresponding try/catch block.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to set the result as false in the catch block, as the value won't be returned(as we are throwing an exception).

Your method should also declare that it throws an exception and so the client will be forced to handle it.

Also consider using a more specific exception which will be thrown in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

You could throw an unchecked exception

```
 Logger.info("fetching feed(%d) failed", feedId);
 throw new RuntimeException(ex);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `throws Exception` to your method. You also don't need to add `result = false;` in your `catch` block.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you handle this exception is really appropriate if any failure of feed.fetchContents() method cannot be recovered. (Idea is better to halt rather than continuing)
Apart from that I would suggest you to use more specific exception hierarchy.

And another thing I got from effective java book is if you write such a method you must document with @throw (in comments) with the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I spent the last hour looking for it since not even the Complete Reference book mentions this explicitly: **unhandled** throw *ThrowableInstance* works only with unchecked exceptions.. And only runtime exceptions are unchecked. By unhandled I mean something like this:

```
class ThrowDemo {
  static void demoproc() {
    try {
      throw new NullPointerException("demo");
    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
      System.out.println("Caught inside demoproc.");
      throw e; // re-throw the exception
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      demoproc();
    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
      System.out.println("Recaught: " + e);
    }
  }
}
```

This example is taken verbatim from the Complete Reference book (9th edition).

The first throw statement i.e `throw new NullPointerException("demo");` is handled by the following catch block, but the second throw statement i.e. `throw e;` is unhandled by the `demoproc()` method. Now this works here and the above code compiles successfully because `NullPointerException` is a runtime/ unchecked exception. If the `e` instance were a checked exception or even an `Exception` class instance then you'd get an error saying the exception `e` is unhandled and you'd either have to handle it within `demoproc()` or you'd have to explicitly declare that `demoproc()` throws an exception using `throws` in the method signature.